# Get all fields of a site content type via REST?

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-rest-api

Anybody know if there's a REST way to get all the field names for a site content type?  I know I can do [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj247177(v%3Doffice.15)#endpoint-uri-structure):

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists(listid)/contenttypes(contenttypeid)/fields
```

But that query will only take the ID for the child [list content type](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-content-types-and-content-type-publishing-a5026d23-8df8-42f6-b0d6-1920880c0d03), not the original parent site content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site content types are off of the Web object.

`http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/contenttypes(contenttypeid)/fields`

Comment: Thank goodness for SPSE, or Microsoft might have to provide complete documentation! ;-)